# Slow to load Devexpress form with data from SQL Server LocalDB database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress, localdb

I have Devexpress form and I have 6 comboboxes loading with data from a SQL Server LocalDB database, but when I open the from, it's slow to load all data for the comboboxes.

I'm using this code for loading form:

```
 Private Sub PanelControl2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PanelControl2.Paint
        LoadUnits()
        LoadCategory()
        LoadMarque()
        LoadStock()
    End Sub
```

and this for `LoadUnits()` and the other 5 comboboxes it's basically the same code:

```
  Sub LoadUnits()
        CombUnite.Properties.Items.Clear()
        Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
        Con.Open()
        Cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from Units", Con)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            CombUnite.Properties.Items.Add(dr.Item("UnitName").ToString)
        End While
        dr.Close()
        Con.Close()
    End Sub
```

I am asking if there is any idea to get the form load faster

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to load data on the `Paint` event. That event will be raised multiple times during the life of a control and often multiple times in quick succession. That event is just for drawing on the control. You should be handling a `Load` event or the like to load data when the form is first displayed.

Comment: You could also give us some indication of what is "slow".  What you consider as slow other might consider acceptable, it's also quite possible that the number of records you're retrieving may influence perceived speed (and complexity of other queries).  You might also see some benefit to loading your data into a DataTable, then binding your combos to that rather than adding records directly to the items collection

Comment: The `select * from Units` query is selecting every column from the `Units` table even though you're only adding `UnitName` to the Items collection. There's no telling how big that table is, but if you query `select UnitName from Units` instead it is almost certainly much smaller and more efficient.

Comment: Also DevExpress controls generally have `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods which stop the controls redrawing themselves while you're adding items. Try adding those outside your while loop.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning please can i know how to use BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() methods with code please

Comment: The [DevExpress Documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit#examples) pages have got you covered.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is im doing a little fault to put the function code on the paint event when i put the code on the load form now its faster than first code
and im using this Sql query

```
select UnitName from Units
```

instead of

```
select * from Units
```